# No Project File in source package zip file

Tags: r, cmd, package, project

I created a package with r studio with the function build source package.
As a result i get a zip file.  But in the zip file i dont have the project file.
How can someone who get my zip do an cmd check for example if there is no project file?

Answer (score 1):

This archive, which is essentially the result of `R CMD build <package-directory>` is meant for consumption by R via

```
R CMD check <archive>
R CMD INSTALL <archive>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a `tar.gz` file, which isn't exactly a zip file (it's a gzipped tar file, sometimes called a tarball), but is similar.  This is the way source for R packages is distributed.

Ralf Stubner showed you how to check the file from the command line.  If you want to do it from within RStudio, the receiver of the `tar.gz` file should create a new project from it as follows:

1. Choose where to put the project.  In R or RStudio, change to the parent directory where it will live and run `untar("pkgname.tar.gz")` to expand it.  (Or use
   some other tool for this, outside of R...)
2. In RStudio, run `File | New project | Existing directory` and choose the directory where the file was expanded.

Now the user has the package available for checking, editing, etc.  (They don't need to do any of these things to use it, of course:  just install the tarball using `install.packages` or the menu options in RStudio.)

Comment: ok i createtd a new project, put the tar.gz file in and run the command untar("pkgname.tar.gz") with my package. But what have i have to do now to do the cmd check. Because there is no build button in my r studio because i created a normal new project not a project for an package. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: You should do it in the opposite order, as I described.  Just delete your project and start over.